In a WPF grid, how can I stop a * column from growing into it's neighbor?
In a HeaderedItemControl, I have a grid for headers:
<Grid Margin="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

It displays properly and the one * column header grows as expected when window width is changed.
The item template has the same grid defined. In the item template, the * column (column 5) has a grid within it with 2 columns:
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Column 1 displays an icon, when appropriate, and is collapsed if the record does not need the icon and seems to behave correctly.
Column 0 (the * column) contains a label with a TextBlock for content, TextWrapping="NoWrap" and TextTrimming="WordEllipsis".
If the text in the label is short, then everything displays properly: the text is left justified in column 0 and the icon right justified in the overall grid column.

If the text is longer than the column is wide, then the column grows a little bit pushing the remaining columns a bit. The text is properly truncated, and the ellipsis is added, but it usurps some of the real estate intended for the next columns. Maye 20 pixels worth.

It doesn't matter how long the text is, it pushes the same amount. Can I stop this from happening while keeping that one column as flexible to grow on wider screens? I've tried all sorts of configuration, even using a single label without the grid and no icon, but it still has this issue.
HeaderedItemsControl XAML:
<HeaderedItemsControl x:Name="ItemsHIC" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      AlternationCount="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Margin="0,1,0,0"
                      IemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemView}">

  <HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContentSource="Header" />

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
          <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </HeaderedItemsControl.Template>

  <HeaderedItemsControl.Header>
    <Grid Margin="0">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18" /> <!-- Accomodates the scroll bar in the items grid. -->
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Margin="1,0,0,0">
        <Image Source="..\Resources\SomeImage.png" Width="20" Height="20" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
      </Border>

      <Label Grid.Column="1" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 1" />

      <Label Grid.Column="2" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 2" />

      <Label Grid.Column="3" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 3" />

      <Label Grid.Column="4" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 4" />

      <Label Grid.Column="5" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 5" />

      <Label Grid.Column="6" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 6" />

      <Label Grid.Column="7" Background="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Foreground="White" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="0" Height="24"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Column 7" />

      <Rectangle Grid.Column="8" Fill="{StaticResource brush_Logo}" Margin="1,0,0,0" /> <!-- Fills header line with color to match, over scroll bar. -->
    </Grid>
  </HeaderedItemsControl.Header>

  <HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="ItemsGrid" Margin="0,1,0,0" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ItemsHIC}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Column 0 Record Type Icon -->
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Resources/TypeIcon.png"
               Width="20" Height="20" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <Label Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" Height="24"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Content="{Binding Column1Data}" />

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <Label Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" Height="24"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Content="{Binding Column2Data}" />

        <!-- Column 3 -->
        <Label Grid.Column="3" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" Height="24" 
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Content="{Binding Column3Data}" />

        <!-- Column 4 -->
        <Label Grid.Column="4" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" Height="24"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Content="{Binding Column4Data}" />
                
        <!-- Column 5 with Optional Icon -->
        <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" BorderBrush="White"> <!-- Border makes the background consistent across inner grid. -->
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Padding="5,0,5,0" Background="Transparent" MinHeight="24"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="True">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding PotentiallyLongString}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                <TextBlock.ToolTip> <!-- Tooltip is only enabled if the string is trimmed. -->
                  <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource trimmedVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <ToolTip.Content>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding PotentiallyLongString, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250"/>
                    </ToolTip.Content>
                  </ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
              </TextBlock>
            </Label>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="/Resources/Info.Normal.png" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="16" Height="16"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=HasNote, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityCollapse}}">
              <Image.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip MaxWidth="200">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemNote}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </ToolTip>
              </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
          </Grid>
        </Border>

        <!-- Column 6 -->
        <Label Grid.Column="6" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent" MinHeight="24"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
               Content="{Binding Column6Data}"/>

        <!-- Column 7 Management Options -->
        <Border Grid.Column="7" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="White">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource EditButton}" ToolTip="Edit Item" Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, ElementName=ItemsHIC}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" ToolTip="Delete Item" Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=ItemsHIC}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </Grid>

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" TargetName="ItemsGrid" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brush_LogoLight}" TargetName="ItemsGrid" />
        </Trigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</HeaderedItemsControl>


It seems to be (maybe) related to the trimming process, itself. It's like the grid column width is set before the text width is calculated and trimmed, then when it does the trimming, it extends it a bit to accommodate the ellipsis, or something like that...?

It is not reproducible without actual xaml.

So you have grids inside grids? That's very likely the root of the issue. Agreed you need to show a more complete but minimal example capable of reproducing.

Added the XAML for the HeaderedItemsControl.

@EmperorEto I tried reworking it, so the inner grid wasn't needed, but it did not fix the issue.

Your issue is coming from that you dont use the same ColumnDefnitions in ItemsTemplate and Header. The ColumnDefnitions in the ItemTemplate lacks the last definition which is 18 (like in the Header's Grid). Adding <ColumnDefinition Width="18" /> and not putting anything that column should fix your problem.
Update: I just tested it. It fixes your issue, but mess up the column placements. So this answear might not be a good one. I leave it here for now, hopefully it helps a little.

I played with this approach and, initially, it looked promising, but it really doesn't fix the issue. The trimming still makes the column width wobble when the window size changes. It just wobbles a bit differently.
